# tinymce 4 can't add event after init

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

```
$(function () {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#description",
        ....
        setup: function (ed) {

        }
    });
});

tinymce.activeEditor.on('keyup', function (e) {
    console.debug("keyup");
});
```

Above code won't work. I can't add event 'keyup' right after the tinymce is initialized. 
Error : tinymce.activeEditor is null. 
Why ? 
I know this can be solved in initialization with :

```
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
        console.debug('keyup');
    });
}
```

But I really need to separate the initialization code with adding the event code.

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a timing issue.  Your initialisation code is wrapped in `$(function() { ... });` which means that it is executed *after* the page has finished loading.

Your code to add keyup events is executed immediately - i.e. before the preceding code has run.  Hence there is no "active" editor for you to select.

Solution: wrap both (or neither) blocks of code in `$(function() { ... });`.

Comment: Thx. I solved it already. Kind of similiar with your solution.